# eth_getLogs Does not not return timestamp

Tags: go-ethereum

I want to search all the Transfer Event log, eth_getLogs can do this, But does't return timestamp.
is There a way to get it?

Answer (score 2):

Each log entry includes a block number. Call `getBlock()` for that block number and the result will include the timestamp.

Comment: I am ready to fetch basically all Logs about a token, Like 100 thousands, It is really slow to request every Logs block number :<

Comment: Yes, it's painful to have to make all these little requests. If you control the contract you could log the timestamp in the `Transfer` event.